# ASP.Net mvc application always redirects me to login page when i try a new action, even when i am logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, routes, asp.net-identity, action

In short, i built an asp.net mvc web site, a babystore.
I added a new Action in the Products Controller named AddReview() which should add a comment to an existing Product on my site.

1. I login as a user with the Role "Users"
2. I try to add a review(comment),
3. I am always redirected to the loginpage.
4. I try to login even through i am already logged in
5. And then i get the message "Sorry the requested page cannot be
   found!"  on the url "http://localhost:61356/Products/AddReview"

When i add the attribute [AllowAnonymous] the action functions well, so it is not a problem to the action on the product controller.

Does anybody have any kind of information what i am missing or doing wrong.
I appreciate your help!

The short version of the product controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork<StoreContext> _unitOfWork = new GenericUnitOfWork<StoreContext>();
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Category> _categoryRepo;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Product> _productRepo;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<ProductImage> _productImageRepo;

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles="Users")]
    public ActionResult AddReview(int id, string comment)
    {
        Review review = new Review();
        var productToUpdate = _productRepo.Find(id);
        review.Product = productToUpdate;
        review.ProductId = productToUpdate.ID;
        review.UserId = User.Identity.Name;
        review.Comment = comment;
        review.DateWriten = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

        productToUpdate.Reviews.Add(review);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _unitOfWork.GenericRepository<Review>().Add(review);
            _productRepo.Update(productToUpdate);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", productToUpdate);
        }

        return View("Details", productToUpdate);
    }}
```

the whole product controller class can be seen on [ProductController](https://pastebin.com/C52HxfLe)

The form in the view:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Users")){
<div class="bg-white rounded shadow-sm p-4 mb-5 rating-review-select-page col-md-12">
    <h3 class="mb-4">Leave a review</h3>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddReview", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <label>Your Comment</label>
        <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" cols="50"></textarea>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID);
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn" type="submit"> Submit Comment </button>
    }
</div>}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include the NON-POST AddReview controller action in your question.

Comment: Hi Jardine, There is no non-post add review controller action, i only have this action since the non action is not needed. These reviews are part of the product index view, as they are entities which are going to be added to the product class.

Comment: `I try to add a review(comment),` have you tried debugging the code and see if it is saving and if you're arriving at `return RedirectToAction`?

Comment: I will try to add a "Get" add review action and come back to you. I tried debugging and it seems as he never goes into addReview action first, but first goes to the Login Action and then to the addreview(or at least he tries :D).

Comment: Also can you try changing this to your product model;
`public ActionResult AddReview(Product model)` then debug if it reaches the code

Comment: I tried the addReview(comment) and i tried addReview(product), same behavior. The only thing when it works for now is when i add [AllowAnonymous] above the addreview action :(